# how to vectorize autocorrelation of a matrix by rows

Tags: matlab

I have a large matrix [300000, 64]   ( tests )

I need the autocorrelation of each row independent of all the others

result would be  [300000 , 127 ]

I do it this way

```
for i = 1:rw
    xcorrresults(i,:) = xcorr(tests(i,:));
end
```

but it takes most all the time of the program.

Is there a way to vectorize the loop?

Comment: Why is the result a different size than the input? Should be same size. Did you preallocate the output array? That should make it as fast as it’ll go. The only other way to speed up autocorrelation is using the FFT, not sure how `xcorr` does its computations.

Comment: It's linear convolution.  So all the overlap positions yield a value.   IF the FFT could be made to work on just rows that would be nice.

Comment: Yes, `fft` can be made to work on rows, just look at [the docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html). But  you then have a large intermediate array, so I don't think it'll be faster to process the whole array at once rather than individual rows. Just make sure you preallocate the output array before the loop!

Answer (score 1):

You can save a significant amount of runtime by pre-allocating the output (the larger your input, the more significant)

```
xcorrresults2 = zeros(rw,2*cl-1);
for i = 1:rw
    xcorrresults2(i,:) = xcorr(tests(i,:));
end
```

Internally, `xcorr` deals with everything as a column array, and does some additional manipulation if you give it a row. Giving it a column up front saves (surprisingly) a further 35% for me

```
xcorrresults3 = zeros(rw,2*cl-1);
for i = 1:rw
    xcorrresults3(i,:) = xcorr(tests(i,:).').';
end
```

You could use `profile` to drill down into the `xcorr` function if desired. For example around 20% of the runtime for me is for an internal loop of that function to determine the transform length - if your data is a fixed size then this can be determined once and used as an input if you made a similar but custom function.

Answer (score 1):

I suspected the long run time was due to call overhead of doing xcorr for all my sample sequences in seperate calls.

I tried Cris suggestion above.

First i transposed my array so that signal realizations were in columns with lots of rows.   Then padded with zeros so the FFT would be linear.

Then FFT this.  In octave FFT of a matrix works on the columns.

Then IFFT the product of FFT result with its conjugate

tests = [ zeros(rw,64) tests];   % padding

T = fft(tests');

P = fftshift(abs(ifft(T.*conj(T))))';

using Xcorr on each sample with typically 30000  sequences to check was 19 sec.

using the IFFT(FFT(x) .* CONJ(FFT(X))  finished usually around 0.35 seconds.

Now that's more like it..

Answer (score 0):

This computation is already heavy, but MATLAB algorithm for `xcorr` is fortunately efficient enough, it uses `fft` internally. You can still gain near 4X speedup using parallelization on a 4-core machine. Just use `parfor` instead of `for` and use transposed arrays to work column-wise in optimum memory order.

```
clc, clear
tests = ones(300000, 64)';
[m, n] = size(tests);
xcorrresults = zeros(2*m-1, n);
parfor i = 1:n
    xcorrresults(:,i) = xcorr(tests(:,i));
end
```

Comment: For this, I think it would be best to configure the parallel pool as thread-based, rather than the default process-based.